application window pull down menus kubuntu 24,04LTS
Suddenly I discovered that the file, edit,etc pull down menus on top of the application window disappeared. Libreoffic, dolphine, lyx and many other. How can I bring them back?
Many thanks

can you post images of what you are referring to? It will also help to know package manager was used .deb snap Flatpak etc. Were they before and what event changed things? Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly (don't add to the comment trail)
