Disappearing tool bars in many applications
I am using Kubuntu 24.04 LTS. I also use Lyx, Libreoffice, VLC and many other programs. Yesterday, I found out that the tool bar on the top of the opening pages of these programs that lists File,Edit, View, etc. disappeared. I can use Alt+(F,V,E,etc.) and use the drop down menus but the ones that were displayed on the top of the page were much conformable. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

please don't repeat questions. You asked this yesterday https://askubuntu.com/questions/1534456/application-window-pull-down-menus-kubuntu-24-04lts

This question is similar to: application window pull down menus kubuntu 24,04LTS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
